# cardinal numbers into ordinal numbers

Tags: code-golf, string

## Description :

Given an input (a string , array , integer) , Your job is to append one of the following to it.

st , nd , rd , th .

## Examples :

`1 ---> 1st
2 ---> 2nd
3 ---> 3rd 
4 ---> 4th
11 ---> 11th
12 ---> 12th
13 ---> 13th
14 ---> 14th
and so on and so forth`

This is ***code golf*** so shortest code will win in each language.

Good luck and have fun

Comment: a string , integer or an array (choose what you like) , all will be integers or can be converted to integers.

Comment: You probably should include all special cases such as 11th, 12th and 13th (vs 21st, 22nd, 23rd).

Comment: ok. Will do. Thanks

Comment: You are essentially asking for a program to convert cardinal numbers into ordinal numbers.  You may want to acknowledge this in the title.

Comment: @Arnauld : There updated to add that. Is it ok now

Comment: You should explain exactly how the problem works. On the first read-through I was incredibly confused as to what you were asking. It's not clear what the examples are, and I assumed that you were just trying to teach us how ordinal numbers work because it was relevant to the actual challenge for some reason. You should mark the test cases as being test cases to prevent confusion, and also explain the exact process.

Comment: @LyricLy : Ok sorry for that. will do

Comment: There done. Updated both title and description

Comment: You may want to turn this into a [`decision-problem`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem) instead: given a string, return a truthy value if it's a valid ordinal number or a falsy value otherwise (e.g. "21st" is true, "12nd" is false). I _think_ that would be quite different from the other challenge. But please wait for feedback from other users before doing so. (Also, it might be a dupe as well... I didn't check.)

Comment: @Arnauld : Ok will do that. And I can wait for their input. Thanks for that.

Comment: Please consider using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for that.

Comment: @Arnauld : Thanks. I guess I will put it there.

Comment: Hi : thank you @Arnauld , I posted [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16211/79762) in the sandbox